# How to add to a JSON obj

Tags: javascript, json

If I have an object like this

```
const myobj ={
"Computer" : [{ "file" : MyDirectory/A/text1.txt", "line": [23,56]},
{"file" :"MyDirectory/B/text5.txt", "line" :[32,91]}] ,
 "Book" : {"file": MyDirectory/A/text1.txt", "line": [13,46]} 
}
```

and suppose a function yields something like

```
{"Computer" : [{ "file" : MyDirectory/A/text1.txt", "line": [3,6]}
```

Is there a way that I can concatenate this to the list that corresponds to the "computer" key in "myobj" ? i-e can I update my obj to {
    "Computer" : [{ "file" : MyDirectory/A/text1.txt", "line": [23,56]},
    {"file" :"MyDirectory/B/text5.txt", "line" :[32,91]},{ "file" : MyDirectory/A/text1.txt", "line": [3,6]} ] ,
     "Book" : {"file": MyDirectory/A/text1.txt", "line": [13,46]} 
    } ?

Comment: `Is there a way that I can concatenate` - [yes.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Answer (score 0):

//Let "something" be the json you mentioned:
var something={"Computer" : [{ "file" : MyDirectory/A/text1.txt", "line": [3,6]}]};

//Add them to myobj:
something.Computer.forEach(function(t){myobj.Computer.push(t)})

Answer (score 0):

```js
const myobj ={"Computer" : [{ "file" : "MyDirectory/A/text1.txt", "line": [23,56]},
{"file" :"MyDirectory/B/text5.txt", "line" :[32,91]}] ,
 "Book" : {"file": "MyDirectory/A/text1.txt", "line": [13,46]} 
}

var newObj = {"Computer" : [{ "file" : "MyDirectory/A/text1.txt", "line": [3,6]}]} 

for (var i in myobj) {
   for (j in newObj) {
   if (i === j) {
       myobj[i] = myobj[i].concat(newObj[i]);
   }
   }
}

console.log(myobj);
```